# Factoring a number into roughly equal factors

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I would like to decompose a number into a tuple of numbers as close to each other in size as possible, whose product is the initial number. The inputs are the number `n` we want to factor and the number `m` of factors desired.

For the two factor situation (`m==2`), it is enough to look for the largest factor less than a square root, so I can do something like this

```
def get_factors(n):
  i = int(n**0.5 + 0.5)
  while n % i != 0:
    i -= 1
  return i, n/i
```

So calling this with `120` will result in `10,12`.

I realize there is some ambiguity as to what it means for the numbers to be "close to each other in size". I don't mind if this is interpretted as minimizing `Σ(x_i - x_avg)` or `Σ(x_i - x_avg)^2` or something else generally along those lines.

For the `m==3` case, I would expect that `336` to produce `6,7,8` and `729` to produce `9,9,9`.

Ideally, I would like a solution for general `m`, but if someone has an idea even for `m==3` it would be much appreciated. I welcome general heuristics too.

EDIT: I would prefer to minimize the sum of the factors. Still interested in the above, but if someone has an idea for a way of also figuring out the optimal `m` value such that the sum of factors is minimal, it'd be great!

Comment: You could try generating all the prime factors, then generating every combination of `m` to find the minimum error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your second question (which `m` minimizes the sum of factors), it will always be optimal to split number into its prime factors. Indeed, for any positive composite number except `4` sum of its prime factors is less that the number itself, so any split that has composite numbers can be improved by splitting that composite numbers into its prime factors.

To answer your first question, greedy approaches suggested by others will not work, as I pointed out in the comments `4104` breaks them, greedy will immediately extract `8` as the first factor, and then will be forced to split the remaining number into `[3, 9, 19]`, failing to find a better solution `[6, 6, 6, 19]`. However, a simple DP can find the best solution. The state of the DP is the number we are trying to factor, and how many factors do we want to get, the value of the DP is the best sum possible. Something along the lines of the code below. It can be optimized by doing factorization smarter.

```py
n = int(raw_input())
left = int(raw_input())


memo = {}
def dp(n, left): # returns tuple (cost, [factors])
    if (n, left) in memo: return memo[(n, left)]

    if left == 1:
        return (n, [n])

    i = 2
    best = n
    bestTuple = [n]
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            rem = dp(n / i, left - 1)
            if rem[0] + i < best:
                best = rem[0] + i
                bestTuple = [i] + rem[1]
        i += 1

    memo[(n, left)] = (best, bestTuple)
    return memo[(n, left)]


print dp(n, left)[1]
```

For example

```
[In] 4104
[In] 4 
[Out] [6, 6, 6, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, for *m*=3 and some *n*:

1. Get the largest factor of *n* smaller than the cube root of *n*, call it *f1*
2. Divide *n* by *f1*, call it *g*
3. Find the "roughly equal factors" of *g* as in the *m*=2 example.

For 336, the largest factor smaller than the cube root of 336 is 6 (I think). Dividing 336 by 6 gives 56 (another factor, go figure!) Performing the same math for 56 and looking for two factors, we get 7 and 8.

Note that doesn't work for any number with fewer than 3 factors. This method can be expanded for *m* > 3, maybe.

If this is right, and I'm not too crazy, the solution would be a recursive function:

```
factors=[]
n=336
m=3

def getFactors(howMany, value):
  if howMany < 2:
    return value

  root=getRoot(howMany, value) # get the root of value, eg square root, cube, etc.
  factor=getLargestFactor(value, root) # get the largest factor of value smaller than root
  otherFactors=getFactors(howMany-1, value / factor)
  otherFactors.insert(factor)
  return otherFactors
print getFactors(n, m)
```

I'm too lazy to code the rest, but that should do it.

Comment: I like this greedy approach to the problem. It would come down to depth first search in the solution tree with exploring the largest possible factor first on each depth. Yet, in case there is no  (howMany - x)'th factor, the algorithm should also be able to return "no solution". Alternatively, if a prime number is encounted before the desired depth is reached, it could simply return a "1" and solutions with "1" factors could be considered bad.

Comment: In other words: There is no need to call getFactors(howMany-1, value/factor) if value/factor is prime and the next depth of recursion is not the final depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the same principle: look for numbers under or equal to the `m`th root that are factors. Then you can recurse to find the remaining factors.

```
def get_factors(n, m):
    factors = []
    factor = int(n**(1.0/m) + .1) # fudged to deal with precision problem with float roots
    while n % factor != 0:
        factor = factor - 1
    factors.append(factor)
    if m > 1:
        factors = factors + get_factors(n / factor, m - 1)
    return factors

print get_factors(729, 3)
```

Comment: For 4104 you will result with (3, 8, 9, 19), while (6, 6, 6, 19) is better with either loss function.

Answer (score -2):

```
m=5 n=4 then m^(1/n)
```

you get:

> Answer=1.495

then

> 1.495*1.495*1.495*1.495 = 5

in C#

```
double Result = Math.Pow(m,1/(double)n);
```

Comment: Op is using integers, not doubles. Op is also using python, not C#.